# Sore knees from playing squash

Tags: knee-pain

**My situation**:

I am 23 6'1/1m85, 188 lbs/85kg and I play squash at a national league level. I usually train twice to three times a week, always having at least a rest day inbetween. However, when there are tournaments, I often find myself having to play on 2 to 3 consecutive days. The first of these days is perfect as far as my knees go. However, on the following days, I will get sore knees while playing, with both knees being equally sore.

This only seems to happen with squash. I once prepared for a half-marathon and ran 10+km everyday for about 3 months, and I've never experienced trouble with my knees.

**What I've read**:

Apparently the problem I have is short quads and/or short hamstrings, or quads that are not equally strong on both sides of the knee. I don't think I have arthritis because I don't fit the symptoms. Moreover, I should've felt discomfort even when running I suppose. I've had bad posture when I was younger, where my upper thigh muscles were too short and were making my back arch inwards - this is why I think it might be a short muscle issue. Other than that, I have good shoes, and the squash floors have decent shock absorption.

**What I've come for**:

I would like to have your take on this.

1. Do you think it could be something else ?
2. Did you have the same issue with high impact vs low impact sports ?
3. How would you recommend to stretch quads and hamstrings best ? I can't seem to do it properly
4. What exercises would you do to strengthen the quads ?

I'm looking forward for your advice.

Comment: I think the question is related more to diagnosis than sports. As a result, you might want to check with the respective medical experts.

Comment: Does "sore knees" mean sore patellar tendons, painful joints, or what?

Comment: I've discover that it was actually patellar tendons that was getting overused because of muscle imbalance. Some correcting exercises and it all went away.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at your diet and especially your natural collagen production. This for me was an issue I had with perthes disease. Eating high nutrient dense foods really help, especially at high intense sports like squash where you need to make sure your body is producing plenty of grease / synovial fluids at other to ensure efficient working of joints and more importantly recovery. Alot of people look for other problems, but the food you eat / fuel you put into your body is important. Especially to assist in collagen production - high vitamin C foods, and minerals from seeds and nuts like flaxseeds and pastachios etc. Also consider in taking natural [collagen supplements](http://naturalcollagen.in/product/colvita-natural-collagen/) at these high intense times, especially to help with recovery. You will find these natural healthy focus on high nutrient dense foods will naturally boost your recovery and regenration of your knee joints...

A swiss ball can greatly help you with strengthening your legs by placing ball behind you and against a wall and doing sitting squat and hold, lunges and laying on your back with feet on ball and then pulling ball underneathe you and back - burns like hell but fantastic natural core strengthening exercise.

Also remember your stomach strength and core - so plenty of planks and again stomach exercises with the swiss ball.